# Constructor error, setter not working (Java)

Tags: java

I am a java beginner, Why does this code return null ? What is wrong with the constructor ? I set the name yet the sysout returns null.

```
public class word {

    String name;
    int frequency;
    double rel_freq;

    word(String n, int a, double c) {
        String name = n;
        int frequency = a;
        double rel_freq = c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        word maxwell = new word("bobo", 25, 40);
        System.out.println(maxwell.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare new variables in the constructor instead of using the object variables.
Change it to

```
word(String n, int a, double c) {
    name=n;
    frequency=a;
    rel_freq=c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor declares local variables that are the same names as the class instance variables.  Dont dexlare locals in the constructor.

In other words; use this: "name = n". Inatead of this:  "String name = n".

Answer (score -1):

```
package iran;

public class word {

    String name;
    int frequency;
    double rel_freq;

    word(String n, int a, double c) {
        this.name = n;
        this.frequency = a;
        this.rel_freq = c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        word maxwell = new word("bobo", 25, 40);
        System.out.println(maxwell.name);
        System.out.println(maxwell.frequency);
        System.out.println(maxwell.rel_freq);
    }
}
```

Your local variable, you must set the instance variable Self
//https://telegram.me/javalike

[image]